# What is stellar wind in laymans terms and how angular momentum from the star gets transferred to the stellar wind?

Tags: angular-momentum, astrophysics, stars, plasma-physics, stellar-wind

The stellar wind ejected by stars is a plasma (i.e., charged) and thus can and does interact with the star's magnetic field. This transfers angular momentum from the star to the stellar wind.

Answer (score 3):

The stellar wind is just a stream of ionised gas (or sometimes cooler, neutral material or even dust) moving away from the surface of the star. Winds come in a number of different forms and are accelerated away from the star by a number of mechanisms (simple thermal expansion, dissipation of acousitc or magnetic waves; radiatively driven etc.) depending on the composition of the wind material and the type of star the wind emanates from.

I am not sure what you mean by "transfer angular momentum". The wind material begins its journey on or near the surface of the star and has a specific angular momentum. When it leaves the star it takes that angular momentum away with it. If that was all there was to it then stars would always rotate at the same speed (or at least their spin would only change as they evolved in structure and radius), because the specific angular momentum of the star is unchanged by the departure of the wind material.

Possibly what you really wish to know is how does the stellar wind result in a torque that can spin-down a star?

I can only speak for the area I know about - winds from sun-like stars. These are relatively fast winds of ionised particles. The charged ions and electrons couple to the coronal magnetic field and are **held in co-rotation** out to the Alfven radius, where the magnetic energy density equals the kinetic energy density. At this point, which may be many stellar radii from the surface, the wind effectively decouples from the magnetic field, but has now been accelerated tangentially such that it has a much larger specific angular momentum than it did when it was near the stellar surface. The torque required to do this results in the spin-down of the star. As a result angular momentum is effectively transferred from the star to the departing wind material.